# Functional analysis books for PDE.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I want to study functional analysis to learn about the existence, uniqueness and general form of the solutions of PDEs (because I heard that something like that is done by functional analysis).

I went to bookstore and opened a functional analysis book, but it was a book of abstract algebra, and PDE theory was not written in it.

Are there any books of functional analysis for PDE?

Comment: For very basic facts you can read Rudin's Functional Analysis. If you want to get deep into it you can read Hormander's book.

Comment: I would recommend Brezis's *Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces and Partial Differential Equations*.

Comment: @Kavi: Your have a funny understanding of "very basic" :) When it comes to general functional analysis, Rudin is one of the most comprehensive basic books I know. But I don't know if it is a good book for someone seeing functional analysis for the first time.

Comment: @PhoemueX When I said 'very basic facts' I was not referring to FA but to PDE part of FA. Surely Rudin is great text for FA.